# Prolog: How to tell the difference between a list and a simple variable

Tags: list, variables, prolog

I have a database in prolog I made for my project, which looks like this: `item(item_name, [_features]).`

_features includes: `[feature(_feature_name,_featre_data),feature(_feature_name,_featre_data)].`

Therefore, **for example**, database of flowers, it will look like this:

```
item(cyclamen,[feature(pollens_number,80),
               feature(petals,5),
               feature(grow_places,[here,there]),
               feature(months_of_grow,1,3)].
```

I want to write into a window all the features of a specific item, so it will look like:

```
petals:
5

grow_places:
here, there
```

For that, I must to tell the difference between a list and a simple variable, so when it a list it will print all the inside of it without the '[' and ']', but when it is a simple variable it will just print it as is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [is_list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_list/1)/1. You will need to experiment a bit with it, attempting to understand the 'shape' of a *proper* list

Comment: ... and its complement var/1.

Comment: @swstephe technically, `var/1` and `is_list/1` aren't true complements since `var(a)` and `is_list(a)` are both false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "list" in Prolog is a special kind of a nested term. This is how a predicate `is_list/1` could be implemented:

```
is_list(X) :-
    var(X), !,
    fail.
is_list([]). % the empty list
is_list([_|Rest]) :- % list with at least one element
    is_list(Rest).
```

See, for example, [SWI-Prolog's documentation](http://swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=is_list/1).

The first clause only matches a particular term (the atom `[]` or, for SWI-Prolog 7, the unique atomic `[]`). The second clause matches a nested term that represents a list with one or more elements. (The `is_list/1` predicate should be part of your Prolog implementation.)

So, in other words, a list, whether it is the empty list or a non-empty list, is a term that can only be unified with the corresponding nested term. It is not immediately obvious what you mean by "a simple variable", but try passing terms that are not lists (atoms, numbers, compound terms, and also free variables) to `is_list/1` to see what happens.

However: there are other ways to represent your database. You could normalize your data (like you would for a relational database) and put it in tables:

```
flower(cyclamen).
flower('anemone sylvestris').

flower_feature_value(cyclamen, 'pollens number', 80).
flower_feature_value(cyclamen, petals, 5).
flower_feature_value(cyclamen, 'grow places', here).
flower_feature_value(cyclamen, 'grow places', there).
```

and so on. Usually, you don't want to get too sophisticated with how you represent query results, so:

```
?- bagof(F-V, flower_feature_value(cyclamen, F, V), Cyclamen_Features).

Cyclamen_Features = ['pollens number'-80, petals-5, 'grow places'-here, 'grow places'-there].
```

Or, if you want to group them by a feature:

```
?- bagof(F-V, flower_feature_value(cyclamen, F, V), R),
   group_pairs_by_key(R, Grouped).
R = ['pollens number'-80, petals-5, 'grow places'-here, 'grow places'-there],
Grouped = ['pollens number'-[80], petals-[5], 'grow places'-[here, there]].
```

Now, if you insist to print those in a particular way, you should still start with the query, and format that query, for example:

```
show_flower_features(Flower) :-
    bagof(F-V, flower_feature_value(Flower, F, V), R),
    group_pairs_by_key(R, Grouped),
    format("Flower: ~a~n-----~n~n", [Flower]),
    show_features_values(Grouped).


show_features_values([]).
show_features_values([F-V|Rest]) :-
    atomic_list_concat(V, ', ', VL),
    format("~a:~n~a~n~n", [F, VL]),
    show_features_values(Rest).
```

So now:

```
?- show_flower_features(cyclamen).
Flower: cyclamen
-----

pollens number:
80

petals:
5

grow places:
here, there

true.
```

This is a good approach to printing reports, if you really insist to. The structure that is used to make the report (the list of pairs of a feature and a list of values) is also a good starting point for your own structure, if you don't want to normalize your data for some reason.

If you decide to keep the data like this, and if you want to make explicit the different "types" that a feature that can have, consider:

```
item(cyclamen,
    [feature(pollens_number, exactly(80)),
     feature(petals, exactly(5)),
     feature(grow_places, list([here,there])),
     feature(months_of_grow, between(1,3))].
```

Now, when reporting, you need to define a rule for each "type" of value:

```
show_feature_value(exaclty(V)) :-
    format("~a~n", [V]).
show_feature_value(between(A,B)) :-
    format("~a to ~a~n", [A, B]).
show_feature_value(list(VL)) :-
    atomic_list_concat(VL, ', ', A) :-
    format("~a~n", [A]).
```

This has the advantage that all clauses of `show_feature_value/1` are mutually exclusive, *and* this is obvious to Prolog.

Comment: Your definition of the `is_list/1` is problematic. Term testing predicates should be deterministic, either succeeding or failing. But if you call your definition with e.g. a variable, it will succeed and it will generate (by backtracking) lists of increasing length (until you run out of memory).

Comment: @PauloMoura now corrected, and added a link. Thank you for the comment.